# How do I use a TabularInline with editable fields on a ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many

My models contain a many-to-many relationship. `Measurements` can be part of any number of `DataSets`.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class DataSet(models.Model):
    purpose = models.TextField()

class Measurement(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    sets = models.ManyToManyField(DataSet, null=True, blank=True,
                         verbose_name="datasets this measurement appears in")
```

I want my admin interface to inlines `Measurement` fields in the `DataSet` admin like how a `TabularInline` works with a `ForeignKey` field. This is what I have so far:

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Measurement, DataSet

class MeasurementInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Measurement.sets.through

class DataSetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MeasurementInline]

admin.site.register(DataSet, DataSetAdmin)
```

Unfortunately, all I get are dropdown boxes with "+" buttons next to them that open up the Measurement admin. I want the actual Measurement field `value` to be exposed in the inline. I tried adding `value` to the list of fields on the MeasurementInline:

```
# admin.py    
class MeasurementInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Measurement.sets.through
    fields = ['value']
```

But that gives me an error: **`'MeasurementInline.fields' refers to field 'value' that is missing from the form.`**.

How do I expose editable fields for `Measurement` within the `DataSet` admin?

Notes:
This is a simplified case; my real case has many fields in its `Measurement` model. It would be terribly tedious if the people using the admin interface had to open up a new window to enter data, especially since they will need to do some copying and pasting between fields as well.

Even in my real-world models, the data I want users to edit inline does NOT describe the relationship between the `DataSet` and the `Measurement` -- only the `Measurement` itself. I believe this makes an intermediary model unsuitable for my purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer: you can't.

The long answer: you can't without significantly editing django's ModelAdmin. The InlineFormset factories that it uses are extremely limited, and cannot currently handle ManyToManyInlines. InlineModelAdmin objects are *only* supported with ForeignKeys.

Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Well, not sure to really understand the project you are working on but if you want Measurement `inlines` in Dataset, you may want to put the relation in the Dataset model:

```
class DataSet(models.Model):
    purpose = models.TextField()
    measurements = models.ManyToManyField(DataSet, null=True, blank=True)

class Measurement(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

And in your admin.py, simply :

```
class MeasurementInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Measurement

class DataSetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MeasurementInline]

admin.site.register(DataSet, DataSetAdmin)
```

And using `model = Measurement.sets.through` looks odd to me.But maybe I totally missed the point ?

Comment: This won't work because theres no foriegnkey back from measurement to dataset.