# Displaying selected fields of a M2M linked model in an InlineAdmin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms, many-to-many

In a django app, I have a `HouseHold` model, with a `children` ManytoMany Foreign key to a `Child` Model.
In the admin, I'm showing the linked `Child` instances in an inline, following closely [django docs on the subject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models) :

```
class FamilyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = HouseHold.children.through

class HouseHoldAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     inlines = [ FamilyInline, ]
     exclude = ('children',)
```

I works well but shows a HTML select widget, containing all children from every households (which is very long : 8000+ items)

The I tried adding this form to FamilyInline :

```
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('name','school')

class FamilyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = ChildForm
    model = HouseHold.children.through
```

But this throws an error :

```
FieldError at /admin/myapp/household/820126/
Unknown field(s) (name, school) specified for HouseHold_children
```

I just wanted to show for each children edit line some of its fields (first name, last name, school...) instead of this select widget. Is it possible ?

update : [A solution for a very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797915/how-do-i-use-a-tabularinline-with-editable-fields-on-a-manytomany-relationship) is not applicable, an error saying that Child has no relation with HouseHold (which is somewhat true, but it has a reverse one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *basic* M2M functionality here. Inlines work off the principal that the inlined object is directly related to the parent object being edited. A many-to-many relationship doesn't qualify, as the child is not directly related to the parent, but rather related to an intermediary table that itself is related to the parent. That's why you can use `Household.children.through` and not just `Child`. There actually is a relationship between `Household.children.through` and `Household`, but not between `Child` and `Household`.

For you purposes, though, you can achieve what you want by simply designing the models properly in the first place. Household and Children is *not* a M2M relationship. A Household has many children, but a child has only one household. That means that household should be a ForeignKey on child, and then you'll be able to inline `Child` easily.

Comment: Thanks Chris, you're right.I was really hoping for a solution because I had another M2M case with additional fields...

Comment: but what about children with parents who are divorced and the child lives with both, hense two or more households, hense M2M?